# move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move

Tags: php, file-upload

```
foreach ($_FILES["inputfileSendTorrent"]["error"] as $key => $error) 
    {

        $arqName = $_FILES['inputfileSendTorrent']['name'][$i];
        $arqTemp = $_FILES['inputfileSendTorrent']['tmp_name'][$i];

        if(!@move_uploaded_file($arqTemp, $uploaddir.$arqName))
        {
            $error = error_get_last();
            echo $error['message'];
        }

        $i++;
    }
```

Retorna esse erro `move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpTeiKHq' to './arquivos/ZawabMNHXgvV/2MB'`

Criando a pasta

```
if(!@mkdir(DIR_ARQUIVOS.$chave, 777, true))
    {
            $error = error_get_last();
            echo $error['message'];
    }
```

Comment: a pasta `./arquivos/ZawabMNHXgvV/` existe? Tem permissão de escrita?

Comment: Em ambiente linux sempre verifica o permissionamento das pastas, nos retorna a permissão que está

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Eu dei permissão 777 para a pasta `./arquivos`, porem quando eu crio a pasta nova, não sei com que permissão ela vem.

Comment: @ThiagoSantos Como posso fazer isso ??

Comment: Não tem como responder a pergunta do jeito que esta pois não temos como reproduzir o problema, leia isso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: como tu está criando essa pasta?

Comment: @ThiagoSantos Coloquei na pergunta.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Eu já coloquei o código de como crio a pasta, acredito que já consiga reproduzir.

Comment: Respondido, Lucas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Está errado `@mkdir(DIR_ARQUIVOS.$chave, 777, true)`, mkdir deve usar octal, troque 777 por 0777

```
@mkdir(DIR_ARQUIVOS.$chave, 0777, true)
```

Leia mais detalhes em:

- https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.syntax
- https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php
- https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

Comment: Grato pela ajuda.